# Auto login using registered users in my application to Skype for business online

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have a scenario where web application uses MYSQL DB to store registered users. This web application is integrate with Skype for business online (Web SDK) to communicate each other via audio, video, chat and etc.

I am implementing functionality such a way that all the registered users(in MYSQL) should be able to access Skype Web SDK automatically without asking them to provide O 365 credentials. Because the users are already registered for my application, asking them to provide O365 credentials to Skype services is not a good idea.

So I want to build functionality such a way that when registered user(MYSQL) clicks say on 'Audio Call', in background three things should happen automatically. 1.Creation of user in O 365 if not existed, 2. Sign in with O 365 credentials, 3. Start audio call.

Is this possible implement with Skype web SDK(online) ?

I am new to Skype for business online thing, Kindly suggest if any other ways available.
and also let me about available Web APIs to bulk create O 365 accounts using Global administrator of tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible. For authorising users the browser has to be navigated to Microsoft domain to authenticate users and generate the access token. Only after that, your user can be authorised and users can login into Skype Services.

Comment: thanks for the info , still expecting anywork around as how to manage auto login and all.